# How do I get the arguments passed to a powershell command as just a single string?

Tags: powershell, arguments

I've got the following:

```
function Function-Name
{
    Invoke-Expression (no idea what goes here)
}
```

I want to be able to write

```
Function-Name other command text here
```

...and have this function execute the other command using that invoke call. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you not just wrap it in quotes? `Function-Name "other command text here"` or just use `$args` in your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set parameters to make it so that argument 0 takes all remaining arguments like this:

```
function Function-Name{
Param([parameter(Position=0,ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)][string]$Command)
    Invoke-Command $Command
}
```